# Adding a Meta tags CMS function to drupal 7

Tags: 7, meta-tags

I would like to be able to manually configure the meta tags, keywords and description,for each individual page of the sites. I couldn't find any module out there for drupal 7 that does so. 
Anyone have heard of such a module? If not how hard would it be to make this a custom module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a complete rewrite of the old drupal 6 module [nodewords](http://drupal.org/project/nodewords) in progress now - it is called [metatags](http://drupal.org/project/metatags). However the metatags module looks like it is still in the initial development phase, so you might be better off using http://drupal.org/project/metatags_quick - which already has a stable 7.x release

There is no releases on the project page, but you could clone the git repo and help with the issue queue and submitting patches back etc

Answer (score 0):

As a co-maintainer of the Meta tags module, I personally think it's the best option, but of course I'm biased.  We are making great strides to stabilise it; I suggest trying out the latest and letting us know how it works for you.

Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of the [Nodewords](http://drupal.org/project/nodewords) module.